# How do I exlclude retweets?

Tags: json, twitter

I'm putting a twitter feed on my site using the getJSON jquery method. I'm finding that there are many retweets being posted, which I do not want. I've done some research and haven't found a good solution to remove them.

Comment: perhaps filter by some sort of tweet id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`statuses/user_timeline` has a parameter `include_rts`. Passing `include_rts=false` should do the trick.

See https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline for details.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, unfortunately, I tried adding this but it does not work.

Comment: Are these native retweets or "RT" like retweets?